# Does char buf[100] allocate any memory?

Tags: c, memory

Does the line `char buf[100]` allocate any memory in the stack? I'm assuming it doesn't because it's just a declaration. When I print the address of buf after running the two different code segments below (one fills buf with "test" and the other with "test test"), I get different addresses. Does this mean that buf is not actually 100 bytes, but only 5 bytes in the first case (+1 for null character), and 10 bytes in the second case?

```
char buf[100]; 
strcpy(buf, "test");
```

vs.

```
char buf[100]; 
strcpy(buf, "test test");
```

Comment: "it's just a declaration" ... nope, it's a definition. A declaration would be `extern char buf[100];` If you run the same program several times, you'll probably get different addresses every run.

Comment: strcpy does not allocate memory

Comment: one reason for the difference is address-space randomization

Comment: In block scope, every declaration that doesn't declare a filescope object (function decl or an extern object decl) is also a definition.

Comment: @nquisitivemongoose Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't say "allocate" (as in `malloc()` and friends), but the definition "reserves" some space (100 bytes) for the array.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard defines C using a model of an abstract machine. When `char buf[100];` appears inside a function, it **defines** an array of 100 `char` in that abstract machine. Conceptually, 100 bytes are reserved for the array in that machine, and all the description of the program behavior proceeds as if those 100 bytes were reserved for the array.

When a C compiler implements a program with this definition, it is not required to implement the abstract machine slavishly. It can cut away parts of the machine are not used. If you do not use all 100 bytes, the compiler is allowed to use only the amount of physical memory actually needed to make the program work.

For this purpose, “work” means the actual program produces the same *observable behavior* as the abstract program. The observable behavior includes input/output interactions, accesses to volatile objects, and output to files. If the compiler can obtain the required observable behavior by using registers instead of main memory, it does not have to use main memory for the array at all. If it does use memory, it is allowed to use stack memory or other memory.

In practice, if the use of `buf` is simple enough that the compiler can “see” and “understand” everything you are doing with it, it might eliminate part or all of it. If you pass `buf` to another routine outside the current translation unit, the compiler cannot see whether it is really used or not, so it will have to reserve 100 bytes for it, usually on the hardware stack, in case the other routine does actually use all of `buf`. (Link-time optimization can enable optimizations across multiple translation units, but this is still developing technology and is unlikely to eliminate allocation of such a buffer on the stack—except, if it can see that the routine in which you allocate the buffer is unneeded, it could eliminate the routine completely.)